# Laravel limit registered user login

Tags: php, laravel

I have a deadline attribute (date type) in `User` model by which would I like to disable login for users who's deadline has passed.

For example: if the deadline was 10.06 and it is 17.06, that specific user isn't supposed to be able to log in.

I tried making a middleware, and putting a complete `Route::auth()` within it, but that didn't work:

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
{
    if (Auth::check() && Auth::user()->deadline < Carbon::now()) {
        return redirect('some_not_authorized_route');
    }

    return $next($request);
}
```

Routes:

```
Route::middleware('web')->group(function () {

    Route::middleware('deadline')->group(function () {
        Route::auth();
    });
});
```

`Kernel.php`:

```
protected $routeMiddleware = [
    ...
    'deadline' => \App\Http\Middleware\IsOverDeadline::class,
    ...
];
```

Comment: Can you give the route definition and the provider where you registered the middleware?

Comment: Sure, here you go

Comment: Hm...you can override the `authenticated` method in the LoginController (under `AuthenticatesUsers` trait) because there you would have the user right after he is authenticated, there you could log him out and redirect him to another page? If you would do it in a middleware then you would have to put every route under that middleware, or you want to have this restriction on some pages rather than the whole site?

Comment: 1. Try to see if the middleware is used: `dd($request->user());` 2. I haven't used route nesting but I know it works if you pass as an array: `Route::group(['middleware' => array('middle1','middle2')], function () {...});`

Comment: overriding `authenticated` method worked! thanks